# Dependency Injection in AWS Lambda function ( .Net Core 2.2 )

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to create a AWS lambda function using .Net Core 2.2 using following

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/announcing-amazon-lambda-runtimesupport/

I need to implement dependecy injection to inject DBContxt, Interface for business layer as well.

Since the appraoch recommends to have only static method as lambda function in this class, it seems my constructor injection is not working since the only method executing is the lambda function , i tried to create a static constructor and static initilizer but those are not executing as well.

Following is example code

```
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport;
using Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Lambda
{
    public class DoSomething
    {
        // Configuration Service
        public static IConfigurationService ConfigService { get; set; }
        public static IManager Manager { get; set; }

        public static DoSomething()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Static initializer begin....");
            // Set up Dependency Injection
            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
            ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);
            var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

            // Get Configuration Service from DI system
            ConfigService = serviceProvider.GetService<IConfigurationService>();
            Console.WriteLine("Static initializer done....");
        }
        // Use this ctor from unit tests that can mock IConfigurationService
        public DoSomething(IConfigurationService configService, IManager Manager)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Constructor being....");
            ConfigService = configService;
            Manager = Manager;
            Console.WriteLine("Constructor done....");
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the custom runtime.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args"></param>
        private static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Func<ILambdaContext, string> func = Expire;
            using(var handlerWrapper = HandlerWrapper.GetHandlerWrapper(func, new JsonSerializer()))
            using(var bootstrap = new LambdaBootstrap(handlerWrapper))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Main done 0....");
                await bootstrap.RunAsync();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Main done....");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Lambda function to expire items.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string Expire(ILambdaContext context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Expire called....");
            // Get config setting using input as a key
            var temp = Manager.Expire();
            context.Logger.LogLine($"Processing-3 ..... {temp}");
            return temp;
        }

        static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
            // PostgreSQL Configuration.
            serviceCollection.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql().AddDbContext<DbContext>(opt =>
                opt.UseNpgsql(ConfigService.GetConfiguration().GetConnectionString("DbConnection"))
                );

            // Register services with DI system
            serviceCollection.AddTransient<IEnvironmentService, EnvironmentService>();
            serviceCollection.AddTransient<IConfigurationService, ConfigurationService>();
            serviceCollection.AddTransient<IRepository, Repository>();
            serviceCollection.AddTransient<IManager, Manager>();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get DI running using the mention AWS tutorial and Tony Sneed's tutorial https://blog.tonysneed.com/2018/12/16/add-net-core-di-and-config-goodness-to-aws-lambda-functions/ but calling the DI inicialization from the Main method as it need to be static.

```
public class Function
{
    private static IConfigurationService _configService;
    private static IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Setup DI
        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);
        _serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

        // Get Configuration Service from DI
        _configService = _serviceProvider.GetService<IConfigurationService>();

        // Setup Lambda
        Func<string, ILambdaContext, string> func = FunctionHandler;
        using (var handlerWrapper = HandlerWrapper.GetHandlerWrapper(func, new JsonSerializer()))
        using (var bootstrap = new LambdaBootstrap(handlerWrapper))
        {
            await bootstrap.RunAsync();
        }
    }

    private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Register services with DI system
        services.AddTransient<IConfigurationService, ConfigurationService>();
        services.AddTransient<IEnvironmentService, EnvironmentService>();

        // DI DBContext
        services.AddDbContext<MyDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_configService.GetConfiguration().GetConnectionString("MyDBConnection")));

        // Other DI
        services.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>();
    }

    public static string FunctionHandler(string input, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        var myService = _serviceProvider.GetService<IMyService>();
        return myService.DoSomething(input);
    }
}
```